# zip gets "exhausted" by one loop

Tags: python, for-loop, zip

when I run python script, a weird output confused me, here is the core test-code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = zip(a,b)
for i in range(2):
    for x,y in c:
        print(i,x,y)
```

only output:

```
0 1 4
0 2 5
0 3 6
```

I was expecting to see results starting with `i = 1` as well.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you find weird with the output? Also indicate what you expected which lead you to think the output is weird.

Comment: What's wrong with its ouptput? What do you expect the output to be? You need to clarify your question.

Comment: @JulienBernu I am using python 3.5.2.

Comment: @JulienBernu You are running the code in Python 2. In Python 2, `zip` returns a list. In Python 3, it returns a generator object which will get exhausted within the first iteration.

Comment: Going in to the fist iteration of the outer loop, `i` will be at `0`,then  `c`, being a generator will print out `1 4` `2 5` `3 6`. Based on what is being printed out in the inner loop, I don't see why the expectation is that `i` should increment in the inner loop? It should still be `0`. Coming back to the next iteration of the outer loop, we now go to `1`, but the generator is exhausted, so there is nothing to print in the inner loop. To me, the output (in py35) being `0 1 4` `0 2 5` `0  3 6` makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since python3, `c` is a generator.

So once you've gone over it, it's empty. Hence why the inner loop get executed only once.

See https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: c is a generator only in Python3...

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Who knows... angry people (not me), +1 to even up, I hate when that happens to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = zip(a,b)
for i,(x,y) in enumerate(c):
    print(i, x, y)

output:
0 1 4
1 2 5
2 3 6
```

Comment: Please add further explanation to the answer.